# multiple debug_traceCall

Tags: go-ethereum, openethereum, trace

Is there a way to call for multiple debug_traceCall with a Geth client in one RPC?
In other words - what is the equivalent of OpenEthereum's trace_callMany in Geth?

Answer (score 2):

No, multiple traces are not available in Geth.

You can trace transaction, trace blocks, but not multiple calls

Sources for your reference:

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/tracers/api.go